# Azure website password protection

Tags: azure

I would like to enable viewing a website that I created to one person, whose IP I do not know. Is there a way to hide the website under a simple password (without publishing the page and logging by Facebook etc.)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the person can have an account in an active directory you trust, you can add them pretty easily.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication

Only users that have access to the AAD (including guests) can see the site afterwards.